# How can i solve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, location-href, hashref

i have one page website.
i added smoothscroll with js.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li > a").on('click', function(e) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      e.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;

    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
       }, 800, function(){
     window.location.hash = hash;
     });
    }
   });
  });
```

and here's my navigation html code:

```
<li class="{{ slug == '/' ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
<li class="{{ slug == '/about' ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
<li class="{{ slug == '/blog' ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="#blog">BLOG</a></li>
```

but when i go to another page (like blog), i got error top when click the navigation to go to onepage again.
did i missed something?

Comment: Check value of `$(hash).offset()` inside `animate` function using breakpoint or alert, if it is `undefined` then you know the cause of error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have placed related elements with a correct `id` in the page:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li > a").on('click', function(e) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      e.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;
      if ($(hash).length > 0) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 800, function() {
          window.location.hash = hash;
        });
      }
    }
   });
  });
```

```css
ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class=""><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#blog">BLOG</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="home" style="margin:500px 0;">
Home
</div>
<div id="about" style="margin:500px 0;">
About
</div>
<div id="blog" style="margin:500px 0;">
Blog
</div>
```

Comment: yes, the id already correct. The problem only, when i go to blog page then wanna go to about, i've got error that top value is undefined.

Comment: I guess there's something else effecting your script. Would you post the whole html markup for debugging?

Comment: How about warping `if ($(hash).length > 0) {` for `animate()` ? like my updated Snippet

Answer (score 0):

I hope your hash will be so '#about' and '#home' '#blog' when you get them.

plaease use your hash without '#', because your id is not with "#" right?

Comment: when i used without #, i still got error about top value.

Comment: do you have a content with id="blog" and id="about" and id="home"  ????

Comment: var hash = this.hash.substring(1);
try this one 
and make sure you have content with id="home" ...id="about" ... id="blog"

Comment: example: i open my web "http://myblog.com" then i go to about section "http://myblog.com/#about" and i go to blog "http://myblog.com/blog" but from blog, when i wanna go to about again, which is the url is "http://myblog.com/#about" the page won't working, coz the top value is undefined. but if i remove scrooltop js the navigation work at all. The problem only the top value

Comment: i can't show all html code, but the structure like this
`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse zero_mp" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main-menu">
    <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#our-farm">BLOG</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<section id="home">
  <img src="/welcome.png" alt="">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
</section>
<section id="about">
  <h1>About Us</h1>
</section>
<section id="blog">
  <h1>Our Blog</h1>
  <a href="/blog-category/tech"></a>
</section>`

Comment: change  :   <a href="#our-farm">BLOG</a>

to : 

<a href="#blog">BLOG</a>

and remove  ->  "subtr(1)" that asked you to add above..